# Svn: Commiting a directory that is highly edited with new files

Tags: svn

I have an old SVN repository where the source code gone very far thus lots of new files and directories have been added.

I am curious what would be the best way to commit this new data to the system, assuming my directory is like `http://127.0.0.1/svn/myproject` under Linux environment (thus as a command line). I can think of merge or deleting the directory and resubmitting it.

Comment: This question is more suitable for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your first sentence does not make sense. Could you please clarify it, or possibly get help from someone else to reformulate it? What do you mean by "the actually source code gone very far"?

Comment: If the new source is so divergent, why not just delete the repository and create a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without creating a new project in your repository I suggest

```
svn update --accept mine-full
svn commit -m"your reasonable comment"
```

wich updates your working copy with the latest changes in your repository, while using your working copy sources in case of conflicts.

In case you want to create a new project in your repository you might use

```
svn export WorkingCopyUrl SomeLocationUrl
```

to strip all `.svn` folders from your source and import *SomeLocationUrl* with your method of choice to the new project.